# Joomla Send Mail with JUtility::sendMail sender email issue

Tags: php, joomla, sendmail

I faced an issue in Joomla JUtility::sendMail function

The function arguments mentioned in the Joomla documentation is [like this](http://docs.joomla.org/JUtility/sendMail)

The issue is i can't set the fromemail(Sender email).When i set the sender email and replay to email .The replay to email is showing in the mail is the one from joomla admin config email.
when i set the other email in replay to or sender email Its not taking correct one every time its using the email from joomla admin config.

I got one refference from google [almost same](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=579&t=727297) but I tried this it not working.

I am using Joomla 1.7

I tried with

```
$your_email //can be array but here string one email
$your_name //name i will work fine
$user_email //admin email
$subject //subject
//last two argument is reply to and replay name Its showing inside mail but click on replay it will admin config email.
JUtility::sendMail($your_email, $your_name, $user_email, $subject, $fcontent,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,$your_email,$your_name);
```

Any help will appreciated..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415238/joomla-jmail-addrecipient-with-name/13415814

Comment: Its not at all a duplicate read that question in details and mine.That question is talking about email recivers iam talking about senders!

Comment: Show your code,what have you tried?

Comment: @Tornado added some code for more details.any help

Comment: Try to echo all variable and check what value are you getting?

Comment: @Tornado Yes tried in utility class evrything getting fine,But in the setSender() in mail.php will call that time values taking from admin config

Comment: @Tornado Its a joomla core functionality error.We need to find fixing

Comment: you need to show more than the code you have provided. you have stated 4 incomplete variables and the mail function. what about how you and getting the data?

Comment: He's said he's echo'd out the variables - I think we can assume the data is ok ;)

Answer (score 6):

Try like this

```
$mailer =& JFactory::getMailer();
```

//add the sender Information.

```
$sender = array( 
    $your_email,
    $your_name
);

$mailer->setSender($sender);
```

//add the recipient.
    $recipient = $user_email;

```
$mailer->addRecipient($recipient);
```

//add the subject

```
$mailer->setSubject('Your subject string');
```

//add body

```
$mailer->setBody($fcontent);

$send =& $mailer->Send();

if ( $send !== true ) {
    echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->message;
} else {
    echo 'Mail sent';
}
```

It's done.For more information see this link [Sending email from extensions](http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions).

I thinks it may help you.